# Should I in general partition tables by tenant IDs in a multi-tenant system?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, partitioning, multi-tenant

We're building a system where the data in 10 tables is associated with Accounts. A typical table looks like this:

```
create table Things(
    accountId varchar(64) not null,
    internalId varchar(64) not null,
    externalId varchar(256) as (concat(accountId, '-', internalId)) stored,
    ...
    primary key (accountId, sourcedId),
    unique (externalId),
    foreign key (accountId) references Accounts (id)
);
```

All queries either have an `accountId` in the `where` clause, or they use `externalId`. There are no cross-account queries.

We're expecting to have a total of 200 accounts. The sizes of the other tables (like `Things`) vary from 5 rows per account for some tables (1000 rows total) to 225K rows per account for some other tables (45M rows total). (These are the numbers we use for performance testing - they're the max numbers)

The DB size is ~150 GB. 95% of the scenarios are reads.

The RDBMS is Mysql 8.0.16 (AWS RDS).

We don't have any performance issues at the moment and we're not trying to make anything work faster. But I'm wondering if NOT partitioning the tables like `Things` by `accountId` is a "premature pessimization"?

Comment: +1 for "premature pessimization"

Comment: Having such monstrous keys leads to needing 150GB instead of something much smaller.

Comment: FKs are not supported in Partitioned tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using InnoDB, the clustered index will (generally) already organize the data by `AccountId`.  If the number of writes is generally low/fairly balanced, there should be no need to partition by *every* `AccountId`.

Partitioning might help in the following scenarious:

1. You need to drop an entire account's data quickly or restore just a single account's data.
2. You have a lot of accounts with very few writes, and other accounts with tons of writes.  If you partition the high-volume accounts to their own partition, it's easier to perform things like defragmentation/index rebuilds without affecting other accounts.
3. You need to keep data accessible for inactive accounts, but want to keep the "active" data as small/manageable as possible.

If you do end up partitioning, doing so by every `AccountId` will probably be overkill - it's better to determine some criteria for how/when you'd partition.

Edit:
As RickJames helpfully points out, MySQL can't/won't enforce FK constraints with partitioned tables.  So you'd need to create an alternate method of enforcing those, which is extra code overhead and the risk of invalid data.  So if you do end up partitioning things, might make sense to upgrade to a database without that limitation (SQL Server would be the next step up in the "Supports clustered indexes, can implement partitions without breaking" category.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is often more about administration (swapping partitions in and up while updating a warehouse, etc.) than performance in general OLTP scenarios and, especially if all your data is on the same drive/array, can result in a performance decrease.

If you need partitioning later you may choose to do it by a different property, perhaps partitioning such that newer, more active, data can be kept on your fastest drives. If this is the case then you have made more work for yourself as you will need to unpick the existing partitioning scheme before implementing the new one.

So while this is at least a little opinion and not 100% fact, I would say partitioning now is premature.